# Need a snort rule to capture all unencrypted data streams/connection on my network

Tags: snort

As the title say I am wanting a rule (or multiple rules) that captures all unencrypted data that is flowing in and out of my network. I want to ensure all of my important connections are being encrypted. Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks

I currently just have a rule for http
alert http any any -> any any (msg:"Http traffic";sid:100000200;rev:1;)